# Java Android: Ensure quiz answers are different from one another

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm working on an Android quiz app. I've gotten it to work but I'm not exactly thrilled with the algorithm I used to ensure that the answers displayed are different from one another.

Context: I'm taking a hashmap key as a component of the question and displaying its value plus three other random values as the four possible answers.

Here's my code:

```
String corrValue, randValue1, randValue2, randValue3;
    do {
        corrValue = value;
        randValue1 = ArrayList.get(random.nextInt(ArrayList.size())).toString();
        randValue2 = ArrayList.get(random.nextInt(ArrayList.size())).toString();
        randValue3 = ArrayList.get(random.nextInt(ArrayList.size())).toString();
    } while (corrValue == randValue1 || corrValue == randValue2 || corrValue == randValue3 || randValue1 == randValue2 || randValue1 == randValue3 || randValue2 == randValue3);
```

As I've said, the code works but it's not exactly the most elegant solution in my beginner eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your answers are gonna be integers but you need to convert them to Strings for some reason. In that case, isn't it better to make up false answers similar to correct one? For instance if the correct value is 10, then I would put other answers as 8,9, and 11. Depending on the question, you may wanna have 0, 20, 30 or 1, 100, 1000 for a better question. Randoming them all doesn't really seem like a good idea (imagine you are asking x and answers are -600, 0, 2, 102323, awkward no?).

Comment: The answers are Strings, names of heroes in a game. I have an ArrayList with those heroes so I display the correct one plus three other random hero names

Comment: Then why do you think there is a problem with your code?

Comment: I was thinking there is a simpler way besides that huge while condition, something that breaks it down into a shorter checking process

Comment: If I was you I would just random 3 integers and make sure they are different from each other, and then use them as index to get hero names. This way you can get rid of that ridiculous || chain

Comment: Just tried it out and everything runs smoothly, thanks for the help